# How to execute join in the foreign entity

Tags: hibernate

I am working with two entities - `Top` and `Package`. `Top` looks like the below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "top_top")
public class Top implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Package pkg;
    private int package_ref;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "package_ref", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Package getPackage() {
        return pkg;
    }

    public void setPackage(Package pkg) {
        this.pkg = pkg;
    }

}
```

And `Package` looks like the below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "package_package")
public class Package implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Integer parent_id;
    private Package parent;


    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public Package getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Package parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Given a `Top` *a*, I want list of all `Top`s whose `Package`s have their parent as *a*.package.

To that end, I have tried

```
private List<Top> getSubTops(Top pkg_top) {
    return getSession().createCriteria(Top.class).add(Restrictions.eq("package.parent.id", pkg_topo.getPackage().getId())).list();// Throws an error
   // "tried package.parent_id". That throws an error too.
   // In Django - I would have done Package.objects.filter(package__parent=a.package)
}
```

Comment: what's your error message?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: package.parent.id of: com.company.proj.entity.Top` is the error message I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private List<Top> getSubTops(Top pkg_top) {
    return getSession().createCriteria(Top.class)
        .createCriteria("package")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("parent", pkg_top.getPackage()).list();
}
```

Comment: [Official docs] (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) say `By navigating associations using createCriteria() you can specify constraints upon related entities`. So that explains it.